# Invalid Firebase Database path Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a Firebase value based on `DataSnapshot` reference key Value. Below is my code:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("b_ookk_cPt57roK1u7pyc"); 

 mDatabase.child("b").orderByChild("myRef").equalTo(ref).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String path=datas.getRef().toString();
                mDatabase.child(path).child("flag").setValue(flag+1);
```

It is returing Below error

```
E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Invalid Firebase Database path: https://usour-e9857.firebaseio.com/b_ookk_cPt5xroK1u7pyc/b/-M1sQZyp1S1ZKqdzH9ip. 
Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelv.zzqh(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
```

In the below database path that I log.d don't see any Special character even though it is giving the error. How to solve this error

```
https://usour-e9857.firebaseio.com/b_ookk_cPt57roK1u7pyc/b/-M1sQZyp1S1ZKqdzH9ip
```

Comment: In such cases, we use transactions, as explained in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datas.getRef().child("flag").setValue(flag+1);
```

Solve my problem.